# Using custom DB docker-image with Testcontainers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, docker, testcontainers

I'm novice in Testcontainers, so i have a question.
I have application on Spring/Hibernate. I have docker-image (h2testbase) with mysql-base (myTestDb) with data. I run that image in docker with -p 6161:3306. In test/resources directory I have file application.properties. It contains next

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:6161/myTestDb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&&useSSL=false
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.cred=admin
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I use mvn test - it's working. Now I want to run these test with Testcontainers. I added in pom.xml dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I extented class MySQLContainer

```
public class TestMySQL extends MySQLContainer {

    public TestMySQL() {
        super();
    }

    public TestMySQL(String dockerImageName) {
        super(dockerImageName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDriverClassName() {
        return "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    }
}
```

cuz MySQLContainer using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver and it's deprecated.
My test (for example)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        HibernateConfiguration.class,
        SecurityConfiguration.class,
        SecurityInitializer.class,
        ViewConfiguration.class,
        ViewInitializer.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerServiceJTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static TestMySQL  container
            = new TestMySQL("h2testbase");

    @Autowired
    ControllerService controllerService;

    @Test
    public void stationPagination() {
        Map<String, Object> pag = controllerService.stationPagination(4);
        Assert.assertTrue(((List<Station>)pag.get("stations")).size() == 8);
    }

    @Test
    public void trainPagination() {
        Map<String, Object> pag = controllerService.trainPagination(1);
        Assert.assertTrue(((List<Train>)pag.get("trains")).size() == 20);
    }

    @Test
    public void switchHelper() {
        Assert.assertTrue(controllerService.stationSwitchHelper("BLUE").equals(URLs.REDIRECT_DASHSTATION + "/2"));
    }
}
```

And there I'm hitting the wall. If I use mvn test, I see (through docker ps) that container is started. It started two or three times (and mapping go on random ports such 328xx), but then maven tells

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

What should I do now? How to tell to my testcontainer needed port (6161)? How to use parameters which in application.properties? I can't find code examples where used custom images with DB with data.
Thank you in advance

**Update**
Add full result for failed test.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running ru.javasch.metro.junit.ControllerServiceJTest
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
        ?? Checking the system...
        ? Docker version should be at least 1.6.0
        ? Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 97.189 s <<< FAILURE! - in ru.javasch.metro.junit.ControllerServiceJTest
[ERROR] ru.javasch.metro.junit.ControllerServiceJTest  Time elapsed: 97.187 s  <<< ERROR!
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

There some info. I tried tests with MySqlContainer from [here](https://kazuhira-r.hatenablog.com/entry/20170311/1489239579) (with my TestMySql). When I use clean mysql:5.5 image - all good. But when I try add some modifications in container (for example addFixedExposedPort) it's not start cuz port is already allocated. In case when I adding data from script - it's "Could not create container". If I'm trying give it my image (h2testbase), again "Could not create container".

Comment: If your standalone MySQL is running, please stop that or kill it. Though the exposed port can be different, the host port would still be same 3306 if i'm not wrong. If that worked, let me know as I would post it as answer later.

Comment: @KarthikR it wouldn't have sense, because after tests my app connect to standalone MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two problems here.

1. Docker is exposing mysql server on a random port, but you need a fixed port. To fix that you may set the fixed port using `addFixedExposedPort` of [GenericContainer](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/007c3b9df12145f5175a7dd17c476a01e6f1f5b8/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/GenericContainer.java#L783)

   ```
   public class TestMySQL extends MySQLContainer {

       public TestMySQL(String dockerImageName) {
           super(dockerImageName);
           addFixedExposedPort(6161, MYSQL_PORT);
       }

       @Override
       public String getDriverClassName() {
           return "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
       }
   }
   ```
2. You probably don't have database `test`, user `test` with password `test` as it's default credentials in [MySQLContainer](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/29570469df18f999645e7d29290fb4ac5dda2672/modules/mysql/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/MySQLContainer.java#L19), that cause the `ContainerLaunchException` you are getting. Use `withDatabaseName`, `withUsername` and `withPassword` to configure DB and user properly.

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = {
       HibernateConfiguration.class,
       SecurityConfiguration.class,
       SecurityInitializer.class,
       ViewConfiguration.class,
       ViewInitializer.class})
   @WebAppConfiguration
   public class ControllerServiceJTest {

       @ClassRule
       public static TestMySQL  container
           = new TestMySQL("h2testbase")
             .withDatabaseName("myTestDb")
             .withUsername("root")
             .withPassword("admin");

       @Autowired
       ControllerService controllerService;

       @Test
       public void stationPagination() {
           Map<String, Object> pag = controllerService.stationPagination(4);
           Assert.assertTrue(((List<Station>)pag.get("stations")).size() == 8);
       }

       @Test
       public void trainPagination() {
           Map<String, Object> pag = controllerService.trainPagination(1);
           Assert.assertTrue(((List<Train>)pag.get("trains")).size() == 20);
       }

       @Test
       public void switchHelper() {
           Assert.assertTrue(controllerService.stationSwitchHelper("BLUE").equals(URLs.REDIRECT_DASHSTATION + "/2"));
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**:

To turn on logging, add following dependency to `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and create `src/test/resources/logback.xml` with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="org.testcontainers" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration
```

Comment: Still same exceptions. And another question. How to set time limit on creating container? 
It's take 254.273 s for trying. But now it's not creating two or three container. Only one, which shutdown almost immedeatly

Comment: So set the startup timeout you may use [withStartupTimeoutSeconds](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/c91513d9ebfb3051c2ddaf9b0581e7dbb10e236a/modules/jdbc/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/JdbcDatabaseContainer.java#L98)

Comment: Could you share logs of the execution? Or even turn debug logs on for `org.testcontainers` and share them

Comment: actually exceptions from above - that's all I have from maven debug mode

Comment: could you give a complete output of a failed test?

Comment: @llya added output

Comment: I updated the answer with howto add logging, please do that and upload the new output.

Comment: @llya I added logback result in answers (question body limit). It trying to create container three times than i have TimeoutException. It seems, that at first docker create container, trying to reach it, and only than initialize database

Comment: It looks like the problem is [related to usage of root](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/129), try to use another user.

Comment: No, still the same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that when extending a custom class from MySQLContainer the container starts multiple times. In my case three mysql container were started. When I use directly MySQLContainer class everything worked as expected. Only one mysql container is started.